# What is the order of adjectival premodifiers?

Tags: прилагательные, порядок-слов, синтаксис

What are the syntactic and semantic constraints on the order of adjectival premodifiers in Russian?

In English, linguists and nonspecialist users of language alike generally agree that the order of premodifiers in a nominal phrase cannot be varied freely (please refer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) over at English Language & Usage for more details). Similarly, as a native speaker of Russian, I certainly find the phrase **белый большой дом* ‘white big house’ to be infelicitous under most circumstances and would prefer *большой белый дом* ‘big white house’.

Have those rules been codified for Russian?

Comment: Exemplary question.

Comment: I agree. Great question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rosental (Розенталь) provides these rules for order of adjectives:

> 3)      определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными, стоят впереди определений, выраженных относительными прилагательными (последние» как выражающие более существенный или постоянный признак, стоят ближе к определяемому существительному), например: новый исторический роман, поздняя осенняя пора;
>
> 4)      если неоднородные определения выражены только качественными прилагательными, то ближе к определяемому существительному ставится то из них, которое обозначает более устойчивый признак, например: огромные черные глаза, приятный легкий ветерок;
>
> 5)      если неоднородные определения выражены только относительными прилагательными, то обычно они располагаются в порядке восходящей смысловой градации (от более узкого понятия к более широкому), например: ежедневные метеорологические сводки, антикварные бронзовые изделия.

Source: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/63.htm

A relevant discussion can be found here: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2947

Comment: It's funny how "большой белый дом" breaks these rules, as "big" is a much more stable property of a house than "white" is.

Answer (score 7):

You **can** use either example and be correct. On the other hand, we say `большой белый` instead of `белый большой` because it sounds more pleasant to ear and has some kind of rhythm to it, but I will use `белый большой` when `белый` is more important  than `большой`, for example when you need distinguish white house among many others that might look equally big.

Perhaps there is one more reason in this particular case: we have common noun "Белый Дом"  with meaning "building for the government" too, so these two words have a propensity to be closer. In similar way we say `круглая красная кнопка`  or `сломанный острый нож` but nothing really wrong in using contrary: all depends on emphasize.

Comment: A relevant term is ["euphony"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euphony). And another term used in linguistics is ["phonaesthetics"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics).

Answer (score 0):

Property of size is the first, what you see and understand, when something appears to you, than color and some other properties.