# Множественные прилагательные перед существительным

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше использовать и распределять множественные прилагательные перед существительным. Не создают ли обманчивые образы, когда неправильно применяются? И как правильно их писать?

Примеры:

- большая красивая голубая луна
- большая, красивая голубая луна
- большая и красивая голубая луна
- большая, красивая, голубая луна
- большая и красивая и голубая луна

Какой из вариантов правильный, или какой неправильный?

- качественная прелестная шелковая белая ткань

Как правильно использовать прилагательные в этом случае? И какой принцип упорядочивания этих прилагательных? Можно ли разместить в другом порядке, будет ли меняться смысл и разрешено ли это? Например:

- прелестная качественная шелковая белая ткань
- шелковая прелестная качественная белая ткань
- белая шелковая прелестная качественная ткань

и т.п.

Comment: Related: [What is the order of adjectival premodifiers?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-the-order-of-adjectival-premodifiers)

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере используются неоднородные определения, т.е. такие определения, которые описывают разные качества определяемого слова. Между неоднородными определения не ставятся запятые и союз и. При этом непосредственно к определяемому слову относится только ближайшее определение, а другие относятся к сочетанию определяемого существительного с первым определением.

Во втором примере прилагательные `прелестная` и `качественная` являются однородными и должны разделяться запятыми или союзом `и`. Они описывают словосочетание `шелковая белая ткань` и, поэтому не могут перемежаться или идти после прилагательных `шелковая` и `белая`, являющихся неоднородными определениями.